# How to integrate html into magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have few **HTML** files.

I am a beginner in version 1.9.

I want to integrate those file into my **custom theme**.

What procedure should I follow to complete this task?

Comment: Pls check my answer if it helps you then and upvote me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to magento.stackexchange.com! This question is quite a bit broad at this involves quite a lot. You might consider starting with the offical guide for the Magento 1.9. RWD theme: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/RWD_dev-guide.html